# What is the purpose for passing "window" and "undefined" to a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

```
(function($,window,undefined){
...
})(jQuery,this)
```

I often see codes like above. I understand it passes `jQuery` to the anonymous function as `$` so inside it `jQuery` can be referred to by `$`. But what is the purpose for passing `window` while `window` is a global variable which you can call anywhere? And why define an `undefined` parameter while its not being used at all?

Comment: That is a matter of preference in passing those parameters, since those are global objects, that can be accessed inside that IIFE without passing and receiving it.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy It is not only a preference. It encapsulates the use of global variables which results in a more robust piece of code.

Comment: @Tim Yeah that is for sure. But I was telling about the passing and receiving the global objects inside of it. `(function(){ var jQ = $; var window = this; })();` This is also possible. That is why I told that that was a matter of preference.